# Mongoose JS promises? Or how to manage batch save

Tags: mongodb, synchronization, mongoose

How do I manage batch save in Mongoose? I saw it may not be possible yet:

- [How can I save multiple documents concurrently in Mongoose/Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266512/how-can-i-save-multiple-documents-concurrently-in-mongoose-node-js)

Theres some mention about using some flow control library like [`q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), but I also notice there [promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_mongoose-Promise) in mongoose, can it be used? Can I do like in jQuery Deferred/Promises

```
$.when(obj1.save(), obj2.save(), obj3.save()).then ->
    # do something?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback) function of the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module.

```
var functions = [];

for (var i=0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    functions.push((function(doc) {
        return function(callback) {
            doc.save(callback);
        };
    })(docs[i]));
}

async.parallel(functions, function(err, results) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do this with promises.  If you were using the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) promise library, you could re-write @matz3's code like:

```
var tasks = [];

for (var i=0; i < docs.length; i++) {
  tasks.push(docs[i].save());
}

Q.all(tasks)
  .then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

We start all the operations one at a time in the loop, but we don't wait for any of them to complete, so they run in parallel.  We add a promise (that acts like a placeholder for the result) to an array.  We then wait for all the promises in the array of promises to complete.

Most good [Promises/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) compatible libraries have some equivalent to `Q.all`

Comment: New to this so might be wrong. But your save() there when building the array, shouldn't you exclude the () so it doesn't evaluate while building the array?

Comment: No, I'm starting the operations in the array, so I need to include the `()`.  That then returns a `promise` object that I put in the array.  It's parallel because I only get a promise, not the actual final result.  At the end, I then wait for those promises to resolve.

Comment: If I were to omit the `()` I'd get an array of functions, and there's no universally recognised thing to do with an array of functions.  For example, I might want them to execute one at a time rather than in parallel, or they might take a callback rather than returning a promise.  There is however, one recognised way to wait for an array of promises to be fulfilled.

Comment: I don't think save() returns a promise though.

Comment: If it doesn't, then that's most likely a bug with mongoose.  It correctly returns promises from executed queries.  If it doesn't use promises by default you could replace `docs[i].save()` with `Q.denodeify(docs[i].save.bind(docs[i]))()` to get a promise from a callback based function.

Comment: .save does not return a promise. Why?

Comment: Looks like `Model#save` [will return a promise from 3.10](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1431#issuecomment-34301550). Total good news.

Answer (score 6):

mongoose now allows you to choose which Promise implementation.

Here I am using the node.js default system Promise (ES6) baked into nodejs

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // use system implementation

Promise.all(obj1.save(), obj2.save(), obj3.save())
.then(function(resultSaves) {

    console.log('parallel promise save result :');
    console.log(resultSaves);
    mongoose.disconnect();

}).catch(function(err) {

    console.log('ERROR on promise save :');
    console.log(err);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

node --version
v4.1.1

mongoose@4.1.8

Answer (score 6):

Since `mongoose` now supports promises you may use `Promise.all().then()`, so it will return when all promises are resolved.

```
Promise.all([
  obj1.save(),
  obj2.save(),
  obj3.save()
])
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

In fact, if you're always calling the `save()` method you can use the `Array.map()` here:

```
Promise.all([ obj1, obj2, obj3 ].map( obj => obj.save() )
```

Aaand also use es6 syntax to destructure the resulting array:

```
Promise.all(
  [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ]
  .map( obj => obj.save() )
)
.then( ([ savedObj1, savedObj2, savedObj3 ]) => {
   // do something with your saved objects...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

To save multiple mongoose docs in parallel, you can do something simple like this (assuming you have an array named `docs` of documents to save):

```js
var count = docs.length;
docs.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.save(function(err, result) {
        if (--count === 0) {
            // All done; call containing function's callback
            return callback();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A refined example on how to use [async parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback) would be:

```
  async.parallel([obj1.save, obj2.save, obj3.save], callback);
```

Since the convention is the same in Mongoose as in async (err, callback) you don't need to wrap them in your own callbacks, just add your save calls in an array and you will get a callback when all is finished.

Comment: Or to batch-save an array:

    async.map(objects, function(object, next){object.save(next)}, callback);

Comment: Thanks. I think map approach is better. But both are fine.

Answer (score -1):

What about [async.queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue).
A simple example:

```
var queue = async.queue(function(obj, callback) {
  return obj.save(callback);
});

for (var i in objs) {
  var obj = objs[i];
  // Some changes on object obj
  queue.push(obj);
}
```

If you need a callback after the queue is emptied:

```
var emptyQueue = true;
var queue = async.queue(function(obj, callback) {
  return obj.save(callback);
});
queue.drain = function() {
  // Every callbacks are finished
  // bigCallback();
};

for (var i in objs) {
  var obj = objs[i];
  // Some changes on object obj
  queue.push(obj);
  emptyQueue = false;
}
if (emptyQueue) {
  // Call manually queue drain in case of the queue is empty
  //  and we need to call bigCallback() for example
  return queue.drain();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@ForbesLindesay Why loading an external library when you can use mongoose implementation of promises and create your own All ?

Create a module that enhance mongoose promise with all.

```
var Promise = require("mongoose").Promise;

Promise.all = function(promises) {
  var mainPromise = new Promise();
  if (promises.lenght == 0) {
    mainPromise.resolve(null, promises);
  }

  var pending = 0;
  promises.forEach(function(p, i) {
    pending++;
    p.then(function(val) {
      promises[i] = val;
      if (--pending === 0) {
        mainPromise.resolve(null, promises);
      }
    }, function(err) {
      mainPromise.reject(err);
    });
  });

  return mainPromise;
}

module.exports = Promise;
```

Then use it with mongoose:

```
require('./promise')

...

var tasks = [];

for (var i=0; i < docs.length; i++) {
  tasks.push(docs[i].save());
}

mongoose.Promise.all(tasks)
  .then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Well, it seems simpler to just use mpromise which is used inside mongoose: `var Promise = require('mpromise');` then use `Promise.all(...)`.