# Mongoose batch save with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

I am exploring using q instead of async - then I ran across the issue addressed here:

[Mongoose JS promises? Or how to manage batch save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913074/mongoose-js-promises-or-how-to-manage-batch-save)

What would this answer have been if I was using q?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See post by @rquinn, this code might not actually work if `docs[i].save()` is not returning a promise.

```
var tasks = [];

for (var i=0; i < docs.length; i++) {
  tasks.push(docs[i].save());
}

Q.all(tasks)
  .then(functions, function(results) {
    console.log(results);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

We start all the operations one at a time in the loop, but we don't wait for any of them to complete, so they run in parallel.  We add a promise (that acts like a placeholder for the result) to an array.  We then wait for all the promises in the array of promises to complete.

Comment: are we sure this works?  save doesn't return a promise, and it is async, so i think the Q.all.then() will be called before the records are actually inserted.  maybe that is not a problem for you.  i was calling process.exit in the Q.all.then(), and it was not inserting the records.

Comment: Ah, I thought `.save` was returning a promise.  If it isn't, then your solution is indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

See my comment for an issue I ran into using ForbesLindesay's solution.  Here is what I ended up with (just added ninvoke to return a promise):

```
var tasks = [];

for (var i=0; i < docs.length; i++) {
  tasks.push(Q.ninvoke(docs[i], "save"));
}

Q.all(tasks)
.then(functions, function(results) {
  console.log(results);
}, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```