# Insert data into mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to insert data for whole current month i.e. `November` every day of this month and every hour of each day and every minute of each hour and every second of each minute. I tried the following code which I tried for one day.

```
const data = [
    {
      'name': 'Name 10'
    }, {
      'name': 'Name 9'
    }, {
      'name': 'Name 8'
    }, {
      'name': 'Name 7'
    }, {
      'name': 'Name 6'
    }, {
      'name': 'Name 5'
    }, {
      'name': 'Name 4'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Name 3'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Name 2'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Name 1'
    }
];

const HOURS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24];
const MINUTES = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (let h = 0; h < HOURS.length; h++) {
            const hour = new Date().setHours(HOURS[h]);
            for (let m = 0; m < MINUTES.length; m++) {
                const n = data[i].name;
                const value =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
                const timestamp = new Date(hour).setMinutes(MINUTES[m]);
                new MongoCollection({ 'name': n, 'value': value, 'timestamp': timestamp }).save();
            }
        }       
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create arrays and use `HOURS.length` and `MINUTES.length`?  `for (let h = 0; h < 24; h++)` and `for (let m = 0; m < 60; m++)` does the same.

What is the purpose of `- 0` and `+ 0`?

Inserting the documents one-by-one will let to serious performance issues.

Anyway, I would suggest [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library, would be similar to this.

```
for (let d of data) {
   var startTime = moment().startOf('month');
   var endTime = moment().endOf('month');
   var docs = [];
   while (startTime.isBeforeOrSame(endTime)) {
      docs.push({ 
          name: d.name, 
          value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 11), 
          timestamp: startTime.toDate() 
      });
      startTime.add(1, 'second');
   }
   db.collection.insertMany(docs);
}
```

Or maybe put array `docs` even at top level.

Comment: How can I try that with mongoose? I tried `new MongoCollection().insertMany(docs)`, `MongoCollection.insertMany(docs)`, `MongoCollection().insertMany(docs).save()`, `new MongoCollection().insertMany(docs).save()` none of them worked.

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with mongoose. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266512/how-can-i-save-multiple-documents-concurrently-in-mongoose-node-js#:~:text=Mongoose%204.4%20added%20a%20method%20called%20insertMany