# Store many documents to mongoose fast

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to insert `10K` documents as fast as possible but it's taking a long time.

I am currently using `Model.create([<huge array here>])` to do this.

Would it help to use multiple connections to the database? For example have 10 connections saving `1K` each?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266512/how-can-i-save-multiple-documents-concurrently-in-mongoose-node-js)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `model.insertMany(doc, options)`.

Some stuff to note below.

##### Connection Pool

10 connections is usually sufficient, but it greatly depends on your hardware. Opening up more connections may slow down your server.

> In some cases, the number of connections between the applications and
> the database can overwhelm the ability of the server to handle
> requests.

##### Options

There are a couple of options for insertMany that can speed up insertion.

> [options.lean «Boolean» = false] if true, skips hydrating and
> validating the documents. This option is useful if you need the extra
> performance, but Mongoose won't validate the documents before
> inserting.

> [options.limit «Number» = null] this limits the number of documents
> being processed (validation/casting) by mongoose in parallel, this
> does NOT send the documents in batches to MongoDB. Use this option if
> you're processing a large number of documents and your app is running
> out of memory.

##### Write concern

Setting options on `writeConcern` in options can also affect performance.

> If applications specify write concerns that include the j option,
> mongod will decrease the duration between journal writes, which can
> increase the overall write load.

Comment: Do you have any input on the idea of splitting the 10K model.insertMany into 10 separate requests to use 10 separate connections? Would this be faster?

Comment: How big is your document? What is your use case? If you want this kind of comparison you have to run your own test.

Answer (score 0):

Use db.collection.insertMany([])

insertMany will accept array of objects and this is use to perform bulk insertions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).